# Getting this.input.charCodeAt is not a function when mounting components in test bed for Angular 13

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

We are performing cypress component test for angular components. While doing this process we created `cy-spec` file and mounted the components. While mounting the components we get the error `this.input.charCodeAt is not a function`

We are using `cypress-angular-unit-test` for the component tests.

**button.component.html**

```
<button class="nexus-btn">Click me!</button>
```

**button.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html'
})
export class ButtonComponent {

}
```

**button.component.cy-spec.ts**

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import { setConfig, initEnv, mount } from 'cypress-angular-unit-test';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';
import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NxsAngularModule } from '@nxs/angular';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {Locators} from './button.component.const'
import {DESKTOP, TAB_LANDSCAPE, TAB_PORTRAIT, MOBILE} from '../../constants'


describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ButtonComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    setConfig({
      stylesheet: 'src/styles.css'
    });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    initEnv(ButtonComponent, {
      imports: [NxsAngularModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
    });

    const fixture = mount(ButtonComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `package.json` try to update the raw-loader version to 1.0.0.
This is the compatible version for angular-cypress integration

`"raw-loader": "1.0.0",`